# MongoDB Aggregate Records from Today

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I'm using the MongoDB aggregation framework to aggregate a collection of records.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
Record._get_collection().aggregate([
        { "$match": {
            "system_id": system.id
        }},
...
```

How do I transform this to aggregate records for **today only**?

A `Record` document has a `utc_timestamp` field, so I think it would be something like:

```
Record._get_collection().aggregate([
        { "$match": {
            "system_id": system.id,
            { "$dayOfMonth": "$utc_timestamp" }: 5
        }},
...
```

Is this correct?

Comment: what's the format of the utc_timestamp field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to just get the records for the current day you still basically need to pass in a date range representing the start of the day and the end of the range to look for. Presuming you have implemented this in your class with a [DateTimeField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.DateTimeField) then MongoDB will be using the [BSON date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type which is compatible with the date aggregation operators:

```
Record._get_collection().Aggregate([
   { "$match": {
       "system_id": system.id,
       "utc_timestamp": { 
           "$gte": datetime.datetime(2014,9,6)
           "$lt": datetime.datetime(2014,9,7)
       }
   }},
   { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$utc_timestamp" }
         ....
```

At the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) level these operators usually make the most sense when aggregating values over a wider range than one day or otherwise by hour or minute within a day. Otherwise, since the dates are already selected then everything is the current day and any aggregation key for either another field or `Null` value is essentially aggregating for that day.

If instead by "timestamp" you actually have a number representing the seconds since epoch (the BSON type actually internally uses the milliseconds since epoch) then you can construct your query like this:

```
Record._get_collection().Aggregate([
   { "$match": {
       "system_id": system.id,
       "utc_timestamp": { 
           "$gte": ( datetime.datetime(2014,9,6)
                  - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
           "$lt": ( datetime.datetime(2014,9,7) 
                  - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
       }
   }},
   { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
           "$subtract": [
              "$utc_timestamp",
              { "$mod": [
                  "$utc_timestamp",
                  60 * 60 * 24
              ]}
           ]
        },
        ...
```

Or similarly adjust for miliseconds which is a more common epoch timestamp format by multiplying by 1000. For grouping the standard "date math" applies by rounding the matched timestamp values to the current day.

Finally, MongoEngine supports a [ComplexDateTimeField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ComplexDateTimeField) which keeps the microseconds typically available in python datetime objects. It's a little unfortunate that the actual storage in MongoDB is a "string" in this case, so neither math or general date operators are really available. But the string is formatted as `YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS,NNNNNN`, which is at least "lexically" ordered and therefore can be range selected and dissected with [**`$substr`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) in order to aggregate to a day, or other period:

```
Record._get_collection().Aggregate([
   { "$match": {
       "system_id": system.id,
       "utc_timestamp": { 
           "$gte": "2014,09,06", "$lt": "2014,09,07"
       }
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": { "$substr": [ "$utc_timestamp", 0, 10 ] }
       ...
```

But if you are using any other form of string then you are going to have problems, as it will not likely convert well for either query matching or grouping key selection. In that case you would be best off converting any such strings to use one of the forms above, with the obvious preference on using a native BSON date type as this is the best supported form.